# Rearrange xml node

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an application that displays an image slideshow. Very basic. The slideshow reads from an xml file to load the images.

I also have the images placed in a grid on a page so if the user wants to delete any images they can. If the user deletes an image it removes it from the xml file and re-saves the xml file.

I would like to find a way (if possible) to allow the user to drag the thumbnails around on the page (or whatever way) to put the in the order they want it to be then to re-save the xml file.

I know I should probably have the images in an Mysql database instead of a xml file but it's not and i'm afraid it can't be! That would probably be the best way. Is there a way to allow the user to move (drag) around the thumbnails on the page, re-order and save the xml nodes newest position?

#### Her is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<slideshow>
  <image idtrack="users uploaded file" src="myPhotosResized/594836175.jpg" desc="" original-img-src="myPhotosResized/594836175.jpg"/>
  <image idtrack="users uploaded file" src="myPhotosResized/858077808.jpg" desc="" original-img-src="myPhotosResized/858077808.jpg"/>
  <image idtrack="users uploaded file" src="myPhotosResized/515348713.jpg" desc="" original-img-src="myPhotosResized/515348713.jpg"/>
  <image idtrack="users uploaded file" src="myPhotosResized/852896045.jpg" desc="" original-img-src="myPhotosResized/852896045.jpg"/>
  <image idtrack="users uploaded file" src="myPhotosResized/770816037.jpg" desc="" original-img-src="myPhotosResized/770816037.jpg"/>
</slideshow>
```

#### Here is my Javascript code to display the slideshow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myPhotos.xml?"+Math.random(),
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find("image").each(function(n) // Finds each image in the xml file
                {
                    var companyID = $(this).attr("idtrack"); // Company ID
                    var picURL = $(this).attr("src"); // Path of image
                    var picDesc = $(this).attr("desc"); // Pic description

                    // This appends the images to the slide show from the xml
                    $("#photo-ads").append('<a id="' + companyID + '" href="' + picURL + '"><span class="desc"><p class="ads-text">' + picDesc + '</p></span><img src="' + picURL + '"/></a>');

                    // This shows the text with the ad
                    $('a:has(span)').html(function() {

                        if (this.picDesc == '0') {
                            $('span', this).stop().fadeIn();
                        };
                        $('span', this).fadeIn();
                    }, function() {
                        $('span', this).stop(true, false).fadeOut();
                    });
                });
            $('#photo-ads').cycle({
                fx: 'fade'
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you paste your javascript code

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I placed my javascript code but that's to just display the slideshow! -  I'm looking to find a way to have the user to be able to change the order of the xml file the way the want! :)